# hiding row of kendo grid after saving mvc 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-grid

im having trouble on solving an issue in my project right now. heres a scenario: im a worker and i want to apply for a shift for a position(ex. monday 8am - 12nn). then it will disappear in my grid after i applied. my problem is i want to display the shift again if other worker logs in and they can applyif they want to apply to that shift.

here's my code:

controller:

```
public JsonResult LoadCustomerPositionShiftWorkerList(int? clientCusPosId, int? clientId)
        {
            List<userWorkerCompare> workerDetails = new List<userWorkerCompare>();
            GlobalVariables.SiteMapFile = "ClientSiteMapProvider";
            MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser();
            string userId = membershipUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString();


            var workerIdList = new List<Int32>();
            var customerPositionShiftList = new List<Client_Customer_Position_Shift>();
            List<ClientCustomerPositionShiftInfo> clientCustomerPositionShiftList = new List<ClientCustomerPositionShiftInfo>();
            var filterList = (from a in db.Worker_Customer_Apply_Shift
                              where a.LogicalDelete == false && a.Client_Customer_PositionID == clientCusPosId
                              select a).ToList();
            //this is to get workerId
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Worker"))
            {
                var listWorker = (from a in db.Workers
                                  where a.LogicalDelete == false
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      a.ID,
                                      a.userId,
                                      a.FirstName,
                                      a.LastName,
                                      a.MiddleName,
                                      a.BirthDate,
                                      a.Gender_LookID,
                                      a.LogicalDelete

                                  }).ToList();

                if (listWorker.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var row in listWorker)
                    {

                        var cli = new userWorkerCompare
                        {
                            ID = row.ID,
                            FirstName = row.FirstName,
                            MiddleName = row.MiddleName,
                            LastName = row.LastName,
                            LogicalDelete = row.LogicalDelete,
                            userId = row.userId.ToString()
                        };
                        workerDetails.Add(cli);
                    }

                    var workerProfile = (from a in workerDetails
                                         join b in db.Workers
                                         on a.ID equals b.ID
                                         where a.LogicalDelete == false && a.userId == userId
                                         select b).SingleOrDefault();
                    ViewBag.WorkerProfile = workerProfile;

                    var workerAvail = (from a in db.Worker_Availability
                                       where a.LogicalDelete == false
                                       && a.Worker_ID == workerProfile.ID
                                       select a).ToList();
                    ViewBag.WorkerAvail = workerAvail;

                    var workerId = (from a in workerDetails
                                    where a.LogicalDelete == false && a.userId == userId
                                    select a.ID).SingleOrDefault();
                    ViewBag.WorkerId = workerId;
                    //this is to compare customer position shift from worker availability
                    if (clientCusPosId.HasValue)
                    {
                        customerPositionShiftList = (from a in db.Client_Customer_Position_Shift
                                                     where a.LogicalDelete == false && a.Client_Customer_PositionID == clientCusPosId
                                                     select a).ToList();
                        foreach (var row in customerPositionShiftList)
                        {


                            var workerList = (from a in db.Worker_Availability
                                              where a.LogicalDelete == false && a.Worker_ID == workerProfile.ID
                                              select a).ToList();
                            foreach (var Availability in workerList)
                            {

                                if (Availability.AvailableDay_LookID == row.Day_LookID || Availability.AvailableDay_LookID == 76 || row.Day_LookID == 76)
                                {

                                    if (((Availability.StartTime == "Anytime" && Availability.EndTime == "Anytime") || (row.StartTime == "Anytime" && row.EndTime == "Anytime")) ||
                                         (row.StartTime == "Anytime" || row.EndTime == "Anytime") || (Availability.StartTime == "Anytime" || Availability.EndTime == "Anytime"))
                                    {
                                        workerIdList.Add(row.ID);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        DateTime availStartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Availability.StartTime);
                                        DateTime posStartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(row.StartTime);
                                        DateTime availEndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Availability.EndTime);
                                        DateTime posEndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(row.EndTime);


                                        if ((Availability.StartTime == row.StartTime &&
                                            Availability.EndTime == row.EndTime) || (Availability.StartTime == row.StartTime ||
                                            Availability.EndTime == row.EndTime) || (availStartTime < posStartTime && availEndTime > posEndTime))
                                        {
                                            workerIdList.Add(row.ID);
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //to show compared list

                        var toBeList = (from a in customerPositionShiftList
                                        where a.LogicalDelete == false
                                        select a).ToList();
                    //after applying this one triggers to hide the row 
                        var setToList =
                           toBeList.Select(x => x.ID).Except(filterList.Select(y => y.clientCusPosShiftId)).ToList();

                        var cusWorkList = (from a in db.Client_Customer_Position_Shift
                                           where a.LogicalDelete == false
                                         && workerIdList.Contains(a.ID)
                                         && setToList.Contains(a.ID)
                                           select new
                                           {
                                               a.ID,
                                               a.Client_CustomerID,
                                               a.Client_Customer_PositionID,
                                               a.Day_LookID,
                                               a.EndTime,
                                               a.StartTime,
                                               a.LogicalDelete


                                           }).ToList();

                        if (cusWorkList.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var row in cusWorkList)
                            {
                                ClientCustomerPositionShiftInfo ccpsi = new ClientCustomerPositionShiftInfo
                                {

                                    ID = row.ID,
                                    ClientID = clientId.HasValue ? clientId.Value : 0,
                                    Client_Customer_PositionID = row.Client_Customer_PositionID,
                                    Client_CustomerID = row.Client_CustomerID,
                                    Day = GetLookupDisplayValById(row.Day_LookID),
                                    StartTime = row.StartTime != "Anytime" ? Convert.ToDateTime(row.StartTime).ToString("hh:mm tt") : row.StartTime.Trim(),
                                    EndTime = row.EndTime != "Anytime" ? Convert.ToDateTime(row.EndTime).ToString("hh:mm tt") : row.EndTime.Trim(),
                                    DayID = (row.Day_LookID)

                                };
                                clientCustomerPositionShiftList.Add(ccpsi);
                            }

                        }

                }
            }

            return Json(clientCustomerPositionShiftList.ToList().OrderBy(p => p.DayID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
 var comparegrid = $("#positionShiftWorkerComparedGrid").kendoGrid({
                scrollable: false,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: '/Customer/LoadCustomerPositionShiftWorkerList?clientCusId=' + clientCusId + '&clientId=' + clientId + '&clientCusPosId=' + clientCusPosId,
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST"
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 10
                },
                rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#positionShiftWorkerComparedTemplate").html().replace('k-alt', '')),
                altRowTemplate: kendo.template($("#positionShiftWorkerComparedTemplate").html())
            });


});
</script>
```

this code works for one user only..i want to hide and unhide data in my kendo grid for different  log in .

hope someone could help me.
thanks